# AWS: AccessDeniedException when calling ssm:GetParameterHistory on SSM Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I am trying to write a lambda that listens for Parameter Store change events from CloudWatch and gets history data for the parameter by calling `boto3.client('ssm').get_parameter_history(Name=event["name"],WithDecryption=True)`. This method fails with the message:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetParameterHistory operation: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: blah-blah-blah)

Below is what the lambda's execution role looks like:

```
{
  "roleName": "myapp-paramstore-updates-webhook-role",
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:000000000000:*"
          },
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:000000000000:log-group:/aws/lambda/ssm-paramstore-updates-webhook:*"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "LambdaBasicExeRole",
      "type": "inline"
    },
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "kms:DescribeKey",
              "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:000000000000:key/*",
              "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:000000000000:parameter/myorg/myteam/slack/webhooks/ssm-paramstore-updates-webhook",
              "arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:000000000000:parameter/myorg/myteam/slack/webhooks/system-eventsupdates-webhook"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "readonly-ssm-paramstore-updates-webhook",
      "type": "inline"
    }
  ],
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

Before I used `ssm:GetParameterHistory`, there was `ssm:DescribeParameters`, but I needed to get some version info, hence the change. Everything is in the same region, the lambda and the parameters.

What additional permissions do I need now and on what resource in order to fix this?

Comment: As the error suggests, you are missing access to the KMS key to decrypt the parameters. Also, are you using the right credentials when calling boto?

Comment: @jbasko The fact that the parameter has been accessed and its details read suggests to me that credentials are OK. I think the problem had to do with KMS decrypting the values. I need the values for updates so I can show the old value and the new value.

Answer (score 7):

Figured out that the lambda role that needs to access the key needs to be added as a key user in KMS. Basically, permission needs to be granted to a role (or user) to have it use a key to perform encryption/decryption on secrets.

This is done from the KMS console, click on the key name in the list of customer managed keys (assuming that it's a key that you created yourself), scroll down to key users and add the role that needs to use the key to the list of permitted users.